# How do I quiet a noisy furnace condensate pump?

Tags: heater

I have a mostly-finished basement, with the furnace in a utility room off the main room. I feel the condensate pump is noisy, but this is my first heater with one, so I'm not sure if its normal dB or not.

Normally, we're not down there much, so we don't mind the noise (you still can hear it, muffled, throughout the house). But with holidays coming up and guests over, we'd like to quiet it some.

Is there any way to either minimize its action, or quiet it, or both?

Answer (score 1):

My furnace controller has an "accessory" terminal that carries 120VAC whenever the blower is on. I wired a receptacle to this terminal so that noisy accessories (namely a drum humidifier and a condensate pump) only come on when the blower is on. My blower is loud enough to mask the sounds of the accessories. Maybe yours is, too.

Comment: Thank you. This may help remove some noise, but i'd prefer an overall reduction, not just when the blower is on.

Comment: If it's very noisy because it's old, you might consider just replacing it. Mine cost about $50.